# Get the textbox value from external html file within IFrame

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a two HTML files (**index.html** and **external.html**). **external.html** has some registration fields. Using `IFrame`, load the **external.html** within the **index.html**. I had trouble getting the **external.html** input field values.

I used

```
$("#iframeid").contents().find("body").find("#inputfieldid").val(),
```

but it shows undefined error. Also I tried this one:

```
var frameObj = (element.contentWindow || element.contentDocument);
if (frameObj.document) frameObj = frameObj.document;
frameObj.getElementById("inputfieldid").value;
```

but it won't work. Is there any idea to get the values of an external file's input fields within an `IFrame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i came up with answer for my question. Above Mr.Zword answer is worked properly when **external.html** file has been loaded from localhost itself.I have achieved the values While load the external file from server in following ways:

1)In an **index.jsp** file call the **Servlet** within **IFrame**.Instead of give the **external.html** in the **action** attribute.

2)Within Servlet doGet method you have to establish the connection to the server and give the request to the server with proper **external.html** file URL.

3)Finally print the value through the **PrintWriter** class.

4)Now you can get the IFrame values using the following way.

```
var obj=document.getElementById("iframeid");
var n1=obj.contentWindow.document.getElementById("inp").value;
```

Comment: Since your solution includes java I am including java tag to your question.Also this is a trick to get element value. Not possible directly to get value from an externally located page

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var obj=document.getElementById("iframeid");
var n1=obj.contentWindow.document.getElementById("inputfieldid").value;
```

### My test codes:

***und.php***(*containing iframe*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function altr(){
    var obj=document.getElementById("iframeid");
    var n1=obj.contentWindow.document.getElementById("inp").value;
    alert(n1);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="altr()" />
<iframe id="iframeid" src="und1.php" />
</body>
</html>
```

***und1.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="inp" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried this code finally the variable n1 has null value.what i did wrong?

Comment: I will check and will reply soon @sarav-newfort

Comment: it's value is `null` cause you don't have that ID on the current page, it's probably in the other page, where you don't refer to.

Comment: @Daan-yes that ID is in an external file.How can i access the value of ID with in Index page through IFrame? Thanks for your response.:)

Comment: @sarav-newfort i tested and i am getting the output correctly

Comment: @Zword-I loaded an **external.html** file from server.Its get the null value only.

Comment: @Zword-Its working because it has value attribute value **Hello**.But the think is if i want to get the value from the user when submit the form.It shows null value.

Comment: Where is the submit? where you want to get value?...in index.html or external.html

Comment: @Zword-The submit button is available in **index.html** file.I want to get the value **index file** itself.

Comment: @sarav-newfort ok i will add an update within 10 minutes

Comment: @Zword- your updated code worked properly when **external.html** file has been loaded from localhost itself.While load the external file from server, i got the webconsole error as  **Permission denied to access property document@ http://localhost:8080 **. i think its due to same origin policy.

Comment: Yep you cannot get value of an input element from an external page residing at a different location/server